# Odoo13 is doubling new records while res.partner creation with csv

Tags: odoo-13

i'm trying to import res.partner data with csv import.

I did an import compatible export of the child_ids/* fields as i'm trying to generate shipping adresses.

I already managed the corresponding main contacts, but every shipping adress is created twice, no matter what i try.

i tried the following formats

please see the image https://ibb.co/d2kw7fY

No matter how i format it, the contacts are correctly created under the main contact, but i have each delivery contact created twice.

Could anybody give me an insight how to get it ?

Thanks